# AppHostBase.Instance has already been set

Tags: servicestack

I have been working on building my API based on servicestack. All is working perfectly locally but when I just uploaded it to my azure web space I get the error:

AppHostBase.Instance has already been set

the full error can be seen here:

http://taxirouteapi.azurewebsites.net/

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong please?

Many thanks

Trev

Comment: I should be able to see the metadata page at http://taxirouteapi.azurewebsites.net/api/metadata/ but the site won't fire up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't managed to fix this but when I published the project to a clean azure website on a different url it is working just fine.

All I can think of is that there was something hanging around on azure from a previous website that was stopping it working.

So, moving it to a clean azure website solved my problem.

Trev

Answer (score 3):

Did you create your own AppHost class?  If you installed ServiceStack via NuGet, many of the packages create an AppHost class for you automatically.

Look through your code and try to find where the other AppHost is and where it's being initialised.

Another thing is that if you've added it into your Application_Start in Global.asax, this might cause the error.  This is because the NuGet package already includes this line:

> [assembly:
>   WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppicationName.Web.App_Start.AppHost),
>   "Start")]

This would mean it would get started twice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This question looks like it's a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8954916/85785

You basically need to delete the AppHost that was automatically created when you installed from the `ServiceStack.Host.*` NuGet packages.

Otherwise install it from the base [ServiceStack NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack).