# What is the minimum required code to use ServiceStack's OAuth + a custom user table?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, servicestack

I'm trying to follow the SocialBootstrapApi example and set up authentication for my web app using just 4 providers (Facebook, Twitter, GoogleOpenId and YahooOpenId).  I also want to store the user's metadata (FacebookUserName, etc) in a custom schema (the user table is pre-existing).

Is the registration service required?  I'd prefer to just authenticate the user with their OAuth and save the data as a new user immediately (rather than using a 2 step register then authenticate process).

I've tried the following code, but when I GET or POST to the AuthService's URL, I get an error:

```
Handler for Request not found: 


Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /api/auth/googleopenid
Request.FilePath: /api/auth/googleopenid
Request.HttpMethod: GET
...
```

**AppHost.cs**

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase {
    public AppHost() : base("...", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container) {
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

        ConfigureAuth(container);
        ConfigureRoutes();

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
        ServiceStackController.CatchAllController = reqCtx => container.TryResolve<HomeController>();
    }

    void ConfigureAuth(Container container) {
        var appSettings = new AppSettings();

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings),
                new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings),
                new GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings),
                new YahooOpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings)
            }));
    }

    void ConfigureRoutes() {
        Routes
            .Add<Hello>("/hello")
            .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name*}")
        ;
    }

    public static void Start() {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

**CustomUserSession.cs**

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession {
    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo) {
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        var user = session.TranslateTo<User>();
        user.ID = long.Parse(session.UserAuthId);
        user.GravatarUrl64 = !session.Email.IsNullOrEmpty()
            ? CreateGravatarUrl(session.Email)
            : null;

        foreach (var authToken in session.ProviderOAuthAccess) {
            if (authToken.Provider == FacebookAuthProvider.Name) {
                user.FacebookName = authToken.DisplayName;
                user.FacebookFirstName = authToken.FirstName;
                user.FacebookLastName = authToken.LastName;
                user.FacebookEmail = authToken.Email;
            } else if (authToken.Provider == TwitterAuthProvider.Name) {
                user.TwitterName = authToken.DisplayName;
            } else if (authToken.Provider == GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider.Name) {
                user.GoogleUserId = authToken.UserId;
                user.GoogleFullName = authToken.FullName;
                user.GoogleEmail = authToken.Email;
            } else if (authToken.Provider == YahooOpenIdOAuthProvider.Name) {
                user.YahooUserId = authToken.UserId;
                user.YahooFullName = authToken.FullName;
                user.YahooEmail = authToken.Email;
            }
        }

        authService.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Run(db => db.Save(user));
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="oauth.facebook.Permissions" value="email,read_stream,offline_access" />
  <add key="oauth.facebook.AppId" value="..." />
  <add key="oauth.facebook.AppSecret" value="..." />
  <add key="oauth.facebook.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:3000" />
  <add key="oauth.facebook.CallbackUrl" value="http://localhost:3000/api/auth/facebook" />

  <add key="oauth.twitter.ConsumerKey" value="..." />
  <add key="oauth.twitter.ConsumerSecret" value="..." />
  <add key="oauth.twitter.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:3000" />
  <add key="oauth.twitter.CallbackUrl" value="http://localhost:3000/api/auth/twitter" />

  <add key="oauth.GoogleOpenId.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:3000" />
  <add key="oauth.GoogleOpenId.CallbackUrl" value="http://localhost:3000/api/auth/googleopenid" />

  <add key="oauth.YahooOpenId.RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:3000" />
  <add key="oauth.YahooOpenId.CallbackUrl" value="http://localhost:3000/api/auth/yahooopenid" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: How did you get the c# client to authenticate against FB provider ie. what DTO did you use and what verb did you use to auto route this to auth/facebook?

Comment: @user904538 I'm not sure of the verb, but most of the settings are in the web.config file when you install the nuget package - I'll add it to the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - I had installed ServiceStack via NuGet, and that package includes it's own AppHost implementation.  Long story short, the Configure() method above wasn't actually being called.

Here's the relevant question/answer:

[Service Stack/MVC: "AppHostBase.Instance has already been set" error - but can't understand why/how to prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954622/service-stack-mvc-apphostbase-instance-has-already-been-set-error-but-cant)